# 2d game multiplayer rpg with golang and flutter flame

Tags: flutter, go, flame

I am working on creating a 2d flutter flame game with multiplayer support. I have a character moving across the map with a joystick. When moving joystick it generates newPosition(Vector2) and newAngle(double).

To make it multiplayer I created a WebSocket with golang and sending newPosition and newAngle to socket channel. Channel reads the message and broadcasts it to all players. I am sending this data

```json
{
  'event': SocketControl.updateMyLocationEvent,
  'data': {
    'userId': me.id,
    'x': newPosition.x,
    'y': newPosition.y,
    'angle': newAngle,
  },
},
```

When a player receives the data above, it just moves the sprite based on userId.

After connecting my app to the socket, player movement is not smooth at all, it is very laggy.

I already got the closest server. What are the other optimizations I can make? Are there any samples of multiplayer games? What is the proper implementation of it?

Comment: We don't see your code, we don't know what and how you do. We don't know what laggy means (to you) and what your expectations are.

Comment: @icza I don't think it was that bad, it's pretty clear that the cause here is that they are updating the positions and angles directly, which will match the experienced frame rate with the the latency of the network.

Answer (score 0):

When doing multiplayer games you'll have to make some optimizations for the experience to be smooth. One thing that you can do is linearly interpolate towards the correct position/angle (which should be known by the server if you're having an authoritative server, which is the most common), and not just directly set it.

Linear interpolation, or LERP, is built-in to Flame's `Vector2` extension, it can be used like this:

```dart
yourComponent.position.lerp(theCorrectPosition, t);
```

Where `t` is how far towards `theCorrectPosition` it should go, between 0.0 to 1.0.

What you also could do is use `MoveEffect`s so that you move the component over a short duration of time.

I'm doing a short high-level talk on multiplayer games with Flame [here](https://www.youtube.com/live/BafFTK-YClo?feature=share&t=4363), which might be of help for you.